# JavaFX removing more than one circle while creating bounding rectangle

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a javafx application that creates a bounded rectangle around the circles the user creates when primary mouse clicking. The user can also remove a circle with the secondary mouse button and the bounding rectangle should react accordingly and use the remaining circles as its upper and lower limits. The problem with my program is that it does not work when I try to remove more than one circle in a row (it only removes and resizes for the last circle)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class BoundRectangle extends Application {
    double minX, maxX, minY, maxY;
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    Rectangle rectangle;
    ArrayList<Circle> allCircles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox mainBox = new VBox();
        Pane mainPane = new Pane(mainBox);
        mainPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        pane.getChildren().addAll(mainPane);
        mainBox.setLayoutX(10);
        mainBox.setLayoutY(10);

        pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
             if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY)   {
                   Circle circle = new Circle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 10);
                   allCircles.add(circle);

                   pane.getChildren().add(drawRectangle());
                   pane.getChildren().add(circle);
                   System.out.println("maxX " + maxX);
                   System.out.println("maxY " + maxY);
                   System.out.println("minX " + minX);
                   System.out.println("minY " + minY);

                circle.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
                    if (evt.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                            pane.getChildren().remove(circle);
                            allCircles.remove(circle);
                        pane.getChildren().add(drawRectangle());

                    }

                });

                circle.setStroke(Color.BURLYWOOD);
                circle.setStrokeWidth(3);
                circle.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("click circles, make rectangle");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public Rectangle drawRectangle() {
        refresh();
        getMinMax();

        if (pane.getChildren().size() == 1)
        {
            Rectangle rect0 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            return rect0;
         }

        Rectangle boundingRect = new Rectangle();
        boundingRect.setX(minX - 10 - 2);
        boundingRect.setY(minY - 10 - 2);
        boundingRect.setWidth(maxX - minX + 2.0 * 10 + 2);
        boundingRect.setHeight(maxY - minY + 2.0 * 10 + 2);
        boundingRect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        boundingRect.setStrokeWidth(2);
        boundingRect.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        return boundingRect;
    }

    public void getMinMax() {

        maxY = allCircles.get(0).getCenterY();
        minY = allCircles.get(0).getCenterY();
        maxX = allCircles.get(0).getCenterX();
        minX = allCircles.get(0).getCenterX();

        for (Circle c : allCircles) {
            if (c.getCenterX() < minX)
                minX = c.getCenterX();
            if (c.getCenterX() > maxX)
                maxX = c.getCenterX();
            if (c.getCenterY() < minY)
                minY = c.getCenterY();
            if (c.getCenterY() > maxY)
                maxY = c.getCenterY();
         }
    }

    private void refresh() {
        ObservableList<Node> list = pane.getChildren();

        for (Node c : list) {
            if (c instanceof Rectangle) {
                pane.getChildren().remove(c);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last circle you add appears on top of the rectangle; however the rectangle appears on top of all the other circles. So only the last circle added will get the mouse clicks (clicks on other circles are targeted to the rectangle).

The quickest fix is to make the rectangle mouse transparent:

```
boundingRect.setMouseTransparent(true);
```

A better solution overall might be just to create one rectangle and update its `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` properties. That way you can just ensure the rectangle is added once and remains at the bottom of the stack.